# FirebaseAuth not creating new user from Google authentication - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am using the Google authentication to authenticate users on Firebase. The code runs without errors, however, I am not seeing any of the authenticated users under the "authentication" tab of the Firebase console. There is user activity according to the analytics, but there is no record of any of the users that sign in using the Google sign-in.

```
 func sign(_signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInfor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){
    if let err = error {
        print ("failed to log into Google", err)
        return
    }
    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)


    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print ("failed to create with google account")
            return
        }
       // User is signed in
        guard let uid = user?.userID else {
            return

        }
```

I followed the documentation on Firebase and I have enabled "Google sign-in". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `uid` valorised?

Comment: @Kerberos Sorry, that last part made it a little confusing. That line shouldn't have an effect on adding the user to the "Authentication" tab on the Firebase console.

Comment: Nope, but it helps us to understand if it has signin or not.
You can try to add some breakpoints before the returns and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to the issue:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){
    if let err = error {
        print ("failed to log into Google", err)
        return
    }

    print("successfully logged into Google",user)
    guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else {return}
    guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else {return}
    let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)


    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print ("failed to create with google account", err)
            return
        }
        print("successfuly logged into Firebase with Google", user?.user.uid)





})


    }
```

The issue was with the first line of code, where "didSignInFor" was not properly capitalized. Likewise, there was a duplicate function that was calling the same sign-in function, which may have been another issue on why users were not showing up on the "authentication" tab of the Firebase console.